# Doing something whenever user exits particular page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, shopping-cart

I have a internet shop application. I wanted to improve "removing from the cart" feature. I don't want to ask an user if he wants to "really remove" the position from the cart, instead I'd like to allow him cancel the operation.

Currently when user clicks "X" button at the product in the cart, row of table changes to "removed, click to cancel". In the back there is a list of `CartPosition` objects every with flag `removed`. Removed product is still on list, but the flag is set to `true`. It makes product still visible in proper position on the list, but on the view side I can render it another way. When user clicks another "X", previous one is premamently removed from the list and new one is marked as `removed`.

Shopping cart is session scoped `CDI` bean. It means, when I mark some position `removed` and go somewhere else, then go back to the cart, I'll still have one row marked as `removed`. I just don't want this.

I thought about changing the bean to JSF one, then create another view scoped which could keep record marked as `removed` and check if it's empty, if so I could remove the one from list. I have no idea if it's going to work. I'll try this approach, but I'd rather keep my beans managed by `CDI`.

Is there a way to handle this without implementing my above idea?

**EDIT:** @BalusC, your assumptions are wrong. You should rather suppose, that I don't exactly know how can I mix CDI and JSF. I actually use JSF 2.2, what means that `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` annotation is available for me. Anyway I still don't understand the idea. I understood, that I have to rely on some `ViewScoped` bean. It's clear, but how it has to be composed. Can you explain your idea? I tried few things, but it looked it didn't work correctly. For example my `@PreDestroy` method of `ViewScoped` bean was never called and it's constructed lazily only when I try to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the actual remove job in `@PreDestroy` annotated method of the session or view scoped bean.

```
@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    // Do the actual remove job here.
}
```

Given that your question implies that you don't have CDI based [`javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewScoped.html) available, which is new since JSF 2.2, this in turn suggests that you're still on JSF 2.0/2.1 and thus only have JSF based [`javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) at hands, then it should be noted that its `@PreDestroy` is broken in several circumstances. You'd then best do the `@PreDestroy` in the CDI based `@SessionScoped` bean. Alternatively, you could use [OmniFaces `@ViewScoped`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped) which has fixed and improved the `@PreDestroy` of a `@ViewScoped` bean in several ways. It even gets invoked on window unload.

Comment: Does `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` get destroyed on window unload (when a page is navigated using a hyperlink triggering a GET request), if `<o:form>` is used? (I read somewhere that such feature would be introduced in a certain future version of OmniFaces).

Comment: @Tiny: No, OmniFaces has no special considerations for `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`, it's technically also not trivial as that would require impl-specific hackery. The `<o:form>` was during design stage only considered as possible trigger to auto-include the main script in head, but that was later scratched and replaced by including the unload listener script in end of body when main script wasn't already included by another component, as can be seen here https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.2/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/cdi/viewscope/ViewScopeManager.java#L228

Comment: JSF implementations themselves should be smarter enough to do that automatically as done by WebSockets whose endpoints automatically get destroyed on unload :)

Comment: @Tiny: `@WebSocketScoped` is perhaps not a bad idea :)

Comment: @BalusC does it mean I can mix CDI bean with javax.faces.view.ViewScoped JSF annotation? I need CDI (I think) because I use event bus it delivers. I tried first to inject JSF bean with view scope into my CDI session bean, but it didn't work.

Comment: As answered and linked, the `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` is a CDI scope.

Comment: I've edited my question. I still have no idea how to use it, First it looked clear, but now... I don't know.

Comment: Just annotate your CDI bean with that scope as in `@Named @ViewScoped`? If that doesn't work, then your problem is caused elsewhere not visible in the information provided so far. My assumption  was just based on the way your initial question was formulated.

Comment: Shopping cart MUST be `@SessionScoped` annotated, because it should keep information between views. I think it could not be solved with `@ViewScoped` beans as it's not destroyed during the view change, it's just created separately for each view.

Comment: Uh, just keep session scoped data in a session scoped bean and keep view scoped data in a view scoped bean. Just create another view scoped bean as you came up yourself. You can simply `@Inject` one in the other (this only doesn't work for JSF 2.0/2.1 as there's no CDI view scope available and you can't `@Inject` a JSF `@ManagedBean` bean in a CDI `@Named` bean). I have nowhere said to change your current session scoped bean to a view scoped one.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I understood your problem is  the session. One way to solve the problem is to set the list of removed products in a request attribute and remove it from the session bean so that on the next request they will disappear. 
Hope that helps

Comment: This will fail if the page in question has ajax stuff (and thus requires at least a view scoped bean, not a request scoped one). OP already thought of that by coming up with the view scope suggestion all by himself.

Comment: BalusC I don't understand your thought with this explanation. I didn't realize it was a jsf question ( and I don't have much experience with it) but anyway I don't see any problem with ajax stuff. You can decide which part of the page you want to reload. When he says "go somewhere else, then go back to the cart" means a new request to the shopping chart fragment. Am I wrong?